# Python 3.4 JSON sort by key as int

Tags: python, json, sorting, python-3.x, key

I have scoured the internet for half a day and though I keep coming close, but it's always slightly different. My goal is to take a JSON subelement list and sort them by there KEY. Except the keys are Numbers that are strings. Examples:

```
print (json_reply['top']['sub'])
```

**GETS ME:**

```
{'9': 800, '1': 800, '3': 800, '8': 800, '6': 800, '5': 800, '7': 800, '10': 700, '4': 800, '2': 800}
```

So I try and sort it from what I could find on the inter webs

```
sorted_reply = (sorted(json_reply['top']['sub'].items()))
```

**GETS ME:**

```
[('1', 800), ('10', 700), ('2', 800), ('3', 800), ('4', 800), ('5', 800), ('6', 800), ('7', 800), ('8', 800), ('9', 800)]
```

Different but close. Now it seems not to be JSON (which isn't huge as I can still work with it) but you can see 10 comes right after one. I assume because it thinks its a string. I have also tried a JSON sort method but the results are the same, just in a JSON format. The topics I keep finding out there are people looking to sort the the Values not the keys. I have tried altering the given solutions as best I can but they don't work.

So how can I sort this as though the keys were integers not strings so that "10" will be at the end. Regardless if it stays in JSON form or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give it a sort `key`, a function applied to each element to provide a value to sort on:

```
sorted(json_reply['top']['sub'].items(), key=lambda i: int(i[0]))
```

Demo:

```
>>> d = {'9': 800, '1': 800, '3': 800, '8': 800, '6': 800, '5': 800, '7': 800, '10': 700, '4': 800, '2': 800}
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i: int(i[0]))
[('1', 800), ('2', 800), ('3', 800), ('4', 800), ('5', 800), ('6', 800), ('7', 800), ('8', 800), ('9', 800), ('10', 700)]
```

Comment: You are the Man!, I bow to you Sir!